# Oracle create table query taking too long to run

Tags: oracle, join, optimization, aggregate-functions, create-table

I am trying to create a sales table however after 8 hours it still has not run. I have attempted to speed up the query by adding the hints and reducing the timeframe to 2022 only however after 3 hours it is still running. Is there a way to optimise this query?

```
DROP TABLE BIRTHDAY_SALES;
CREATE TABLE BIRTHDAY_SALES AS
--(
SELECT  /*+ parallel(32) */ 
    DISTINCT T.CONTACT_KEY
,   S.CAMPAIGN_NAME
,   S.CONTROL_GROUP_FLAG
,   S.SEGMENT_NAME

        , count(distinct t.ORDER_NUM) as TRANS   
                , count(distinct case when p.store_key = '42381' then t.ORDER_NUM else NULL end) as TRANS_ONLINE         
                , count(distinct case when p.store_key != '42381' then t.ORDER_NUM else NULL end) as TRANS_OFFLINE   
        , sum(t.ITEM_AMT) as SALES
                , sum(case when p.store_key = '42381' then t.ITEM_AMT else NULL end) as SALES_ONLINE         
                , sum(case when p.store_key != '42381' then t.ITEM_AMT else NULL end) as SALES_OFFLINE           
        , sum(case when t.item_quantity_val>0 and t.item_amt<=0 then 0 else t.item_quantity_val end) QTY    
                , sum(case when (p.store_key = '42381' and t.ITEM_QUANTITY_VAL>0 and t.ITEM_AMT>0) then t.ITEM_QUANTITY_VAL else null end) QTY_ONLINE           
                , sum(case when (p.store_key != '42381' and t.ITEM_QUANTITY_VAL>0 and t.ITEM_AMT>0) then t.ITEM_QUANTITY_VAL else null end) QTY_OFFLINE      



FROM CRM_TARGET.B_TRANSACTION T
JOIN BDAY_PROG S 
ON T.CONTACT_KEY = S.CONTACT_KEY
JOIN CRM_TARGET.T_ORDITEM_SD P
ON T.PRODUCT_KEY = P.PRODUCT_KEY

        where t.TRANSACTION_TYPE_NAME = 'Item'
        and t.BU_KEY = '15' 
        
        and t.TRANSACTION_DT_KEY >= '20220101'
        and t.TRANSACTION_DT_KEY <= '20221231' 
        
        and t.member_sale_flag = 'Y'
        and t.bu_key = '15'       
        and t.CONTACT_KEY != 0           
group by 
        T.CONTACT_KEY
    ,   S.CAMPAIGN_NAME
    ,   S.CONTROL_GROUP_FLAG
    ,   S.SEGMENT_NAME
--        )
        ;
```

Comment: Are you trying to optimise creating the table or inserting the data? If you are only worried about creating the table then you can explicitly specify the column identifiers and data types rather than using `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Performance tuning is not something we can effectively deal with on a forum like this, as there are too many factors to consider. You will have to examine the explain plan and look at ASH data (v$active_session_history) to see what the predominant waits are and on what plan step. Only then can you determine what's wrong and take steps to fix it.

However, here are some obvious things to look for:

1. Make sure there are no many-to-many joins. I'm guessing B_TRANSACTION probably has many rows with the same CONTACT_KEY and many rows with the same PRODUCT_KEy. That's okay, but then you must ensure that CONTACT_KEY is unique within BDA_PROG and PRODUCT_KEY is unique within T_ORDITEM_SD. IF that's not the case, you will get a partial Cartesian product from the hidden many-to-many join and will spend a huge amount of time on reading/writing to temp.
2. Make sure no more than one of those joins is one-to-many. Multiple one-to-manies stemming off the same parent table will effectively give you a many-to-many between the children, with the same effect.
3. You are asking for a date range of a month. In most systems, you are better off doing a full table scan (with parallel query if you can) than using indexes to get a whole month's worth of transactional data. If it is using an index that can really mess you up. You can fix this with hints (see below)
4. It might be using nested loops joins when a reporting query like this is likely better off using hash joins. Again, I'm just guessing based on the names of your tables; only knowledge of your data can determine this for sure.
5. Ensure that the PGA workareas are of reasonable size. Ask your DBA to query v$pgastat and report the global memory bound. It should be at its max of 1G, but probably anything over 100M is reasonable. If it's less than that, you may need to ask the DBA to increase the pga_aggregate_target, or you can manually set your own sort_area_size/hash_area_size session parameters (not the best thing to do).
6. You are asking for DOP 32. That's pretty high. Ensure there are that many CPU cores on the database server, that parallel_max_servers > 64 and that you aren't getting downgraded to serial by anything. Ask your DBA what a reasonable DOP would be.
7. Do you really need COUNT(DISTINCT ... ) on ORDERNUM? If you are just counting # of transactions, it would be less work to simply say `SUM(CASE (WHEN .... ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`
8. Remove the DISTINCT keyword. It's not doing anything - your GROUP BY will already result in the results being distinct.
9. Consult ASH (v$active_session_history) to see if you are actually blocked by something, showing some kind of concurrency wait. Your CTAS might not be doing anything at all because of some library cache lock or full tablespace if the database is configured to suspend until space is added.

Here's something to try - again, it's a long shot without knowing your data or table structure. But I've seen enough reports like this to make at least a somewhat educated guess:

```
SELECT /*+ USE_HASH(t s p) FULL(t) FULL(s) FULL(p) PARALLEL(8) */ t.contact_key . . .
```